# Use c++ compiled library in virtualenv

Tags: c++, python-2.7, virtualenv, package

Notes
This is a python-2.7/django-1.6 project

I have a project that requires the use of the [libRETS C++ library](http://code.crt.realtors.org/projects/librets/wiki) which supports python.  I was able to successfully compile so that librets is now in my /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages using the ./configure, make and make install commands.

Now for the current project I am using a virtualenv and doing development using PyCharm as the IDE.  I am not sure how to include this library in my virtual environment.  Is there a way to inlcude global site packages in my virtualenv? Do I need to create a symbolic link to the librets files in the dist-packages directory, or should I have specified where the package should be installed when I did the configure command?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated or if my question is not clear please let me know how I can expound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by simply copying librets.* files from my /usr/local/lib... directory directly into my virtualenv dist-packages directory for the project.